# Redirect Wordpress site except for specific URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, pcre

I want to redirect the entire domain except for a specific url. I tested the following codes, but the entire site is still redirected.
How to redirect a domain in Direct Admin, but a specific address is not redirected from the domain?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^filename\.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^filename\.html$ - [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

how to edit .htaccess to make that work?

Comment: "except for a specific url" - does this "specific URL" (ie. `/enamad.html` I assume) map to a physical file, or is this a (virtual) WordPress URL? Does this _page_ also use other static assets on this site?

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend a simple and single Rewrite rule, avoiding, as you have done, the problematic use of the exclamation point "!".

Try using PCRE [**Lookbehind**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) assertions, so that you can avoid the final **filename.html** substring to be present imediately before the end of the URL string (represented by the dollar '$' character), like here:

```
RewriteRule ^.*(?<!filename\.html)$ http://www.example.com/$1
```